# Using storeId on a Ext.data.Store isn't making unique instances

Tags: extjs, extjs-mvc, extjs4.1

I have a store `APP.store.Posts` that I want to instantiate 3 different times. They will all hold the same type of data, but will be using different parameters when reloading, paging, etc. In a controller, I do this in the `onLaunch` function.

```
onLaunch: function() {

    Ext.create('APP.store.Posts',{
        storeId: 'unclassifiedPosts'
    });
    Ext.create('APP.store.Posts',{
        storeId: 'positivePosts'
    });
    Ext.create('APP.store.Posts',{
        storeId: 'negativePosts'
    });
},
```

Then later, in the `beforerender` listener methods I created on the controller, I do this:

```
beforeRenderPostsGrid: function(grid) {
    var store = Ext.getStore('unclassifiedPosts');
    store.load();
},
beforeRenderPositivePostsGrid: function(grid) {        
    var store = Ext.getStore('positivePosts');
    store.getProxy().extraParams = {'some_param' : 'some_value'};
    store.load();
    var checkOtherStore = Ext.getStore('unclassifiedPosts'); //THIS STORE NOW HAS SAME PARAMS AS positivePosts STORE
},
```

The problem is, whichever `beforerrender` grid is called last, all 3 stores have those parameters. So the initial load is fine, but if I do any refresh, paging, etc. They all show the same data b/c the proxies for each store have identical extraParams somehow.

From what I understood, the `storeId` parameter was supposed to make my store unique, so am I missing a step?

Comment: Is the proxy defined on `APP.store.Posts` or the model it contains?

Comment: The proxy is defined on the model. Didn't consider that would be a problem, but that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same problem. My store instances *were* unique, they each got the same proxy for some reason though. The only way I found to solve this was to include the proxy config when I created the store. The full proxy config had to be included though, here was the actual code:

```
missingStore = Ext.create('ST.store.Attendance', {
    storeId: 'Missing_Attendance',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax', 
        url: 'query',
        extraParams: {
            resource: 'Attendance',
            parameters: '6'
        },
        writer: 'pipe'
    }
}),
partialStore = Ext.create('ST.store.Attendance', {
    storeId: 'Partial_Attendance',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax', 
        url: 'query',
        extraParams: {
            resource: 'Attendance',
            parameters: '5'
        },
        writer: 'pipe'
    }
}),
attendedStore = Ext.create('ST.store.Attendance', {
    storeId: 'Attended_Attendance',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax', 
        url: 'query',
        extraParams: {
            resource: 'Attendance',
            parameters: '4'
        },
        writer: 'pipe'
    }
}),
```

Comment: The comment above also pointed out I am adding the proxy to the model, not the actual store. But if this is the only work around, I will take it.

Comment: I tried moving my proxy definition from the store to the model originally also, but that didn't change anything for me.

Comment: That's what I just did, and it worked for me. Thanks for helping point it out

Comment: I ran into the same problem but solved it by adding the proxy config to my store definition as well as my model config. No need to duplicate it when creating your instance.